# Is this question OT or not?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, scope

IMO, it is, but if it isn't, I'll vote to re-open.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316065/438992

(Please don't downvote it; I'm just trying to get the right thing done regardless of whether I'm right or wrong.)

Comment: Asking for  a list of stuff is _generally_ way too broad a question

Comment: Myeah I'd say it's off-topic and appropriately closed.

Comment: Related: [Is there a canonical response to back up the statement that list questions are off-topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148097) [List questions: community wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334) Closely related: [Pros/cons lists comparing two methods, technologies, etc.: constructive or not?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169230)

Comment: Dear readers, it might be a good idea to stop downvoting the question; it's pretty definitively closed, and it's really not a terrible or unreasonable question. Piling on at this point is only likely to antogonize someone who is clearly a reasonably intelligent, actual professional dev who has contributed to SO. Do we really need to actively _encourage_ him to go off and post elsewhere about the StackFascists over on StupidOverflow?

Comment: @JoshCaswell +1, he's already cranky enough. I'd rather it was reset to 0.

Comment: MSO didn't exist (or I didn't know about it) when this was asked.

Comment: And why is this even getting downvoted *now*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Off topic.

**Too broad**: it asks for a comprehensive comparison of two platforms, and general information on one of them. That's simply too much for the scope of one question.

Note that the list aspect of the question falls under this reason, not the custom off-topic list reason, because the question asks "what is the complete list of differences between X and Y", and not "I have X, give me a list of products which do basically the same thing so I can pick one".

**Primarily opinion based**: it asks for pros and cons, but *those vary depending on the environment, business needs, and usage*. Whether product X has feature Y found in product Z is a factual question, but whether having Y is a pro or con is not.

The subtext of the question is "my business is considering a move to this platform, and I want to know if it's a good idea". This isn't answerable by detached experts with facts. It can only be answered by OP's business by weighing relative costs and trade-offs. To be fair, the question does *not* ask "is it a good idea" - the OP will be making that decision - but SO doesn't know what's good or bad for the company, so responses addressing these will be opinions unsupported by facts.

The question "I'm thinking about switching my C# app to Java instead, in what ways is Java different, and would those differences be better or worse?" is off topic in essentially the same fashion. The first part of the question is too broad, and the second part opinion based. Hopefully the analogy helps clarify things.

This answer intended as explanation for the OP of the question in question.

Comment: +1 for "It can only be answered by OP's business by weighing relative costs and trade-offs" which sums up my original objection besides its list-y nature.